# python parsing with bs4 an xml to get a list of elements

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an xml file containing data in this form:

```
<head xml:id="_2ebf9c0003">\n\nTECHNICAL FIELD</head>\n
<p n="0001" xml:id="_2ebf9c0004">whatever</p>
<p n="0002" xml:id="_2ebf9c0004">whatever</p>
<... other tags and data...>
<head xml:id="_2ebf9c0003">\n\nTITLE</head>\n
```

I know how to get particular elements like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(PDM_description, 'lxml')
title_element = soup.title$
importing all p elements
paras = soup.findAll('p')
```

The question is how can I add an OR inside the query to get a list of "p" or "head" elements? More general how to get all the elements with tags belonging to a list.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
paras = soup.findAll('p' OR 'head')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to your goal, just add a list with tags to your `find_all()`:

```
soup.find_all(['p','head'])
```

**Note:** *In new code use `find_all()` instead of older `findAll()` syntax*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `,` CSS selector, define your tags separated by a comma (`,`). To use a CSS selector, use the `.select()` method:

```
print(
    soup.select("p, head")
)
```